# Firefox Local Storage External Access

Tags: python, firefox, google-chrome

I writing a script which uses information which a website stores in local storage. Chrome stores the local storage db file at the following path, I can parse this database file fine using python.

```
'C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\'
```

Firefox on the other hand stores the file at the following path, but I can not open this file to parse the information.

```
'C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\vrviae08.default\webappsstore.sqlite'
```

Can you access local storage in this way? Is there a much better way to use information stored in local storage than this?

Comment: Which version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: When you say you can't open it: what did you try, and what problem did you experience?

Comment: sqlite3 in python, version 2.6.0. Tried conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\vrviae08.default\webappsstore.sqlite') Error: OperationalError: unable to open database file

Comment: Is it a permissions issue? I don't remember how to check permissions of a file on a Windows machine though.

Answer (score 1):

While looking for a solution to my similar problem I stumbled upon this question. For me the issue was certainly permissions. I didn't want to alter the permissions in the Firefox directories, so from my script directory I made symbolic links to the .sqlite files I wanted to access. This did the trick for me. Hopefully this helps someone.